# Z3 Equation Solver - Bitmask Operation

Tags: python, z3, z3py

After reverse engineering a program, I found the constraints.

I have to find two unsigned numbers such that:

```
x + y = 0xC0ED91BD
```

and

```
x * y = Z
```

In the original program, the multiplication of the numbers is performed using imul instruction.

Z should be such that when only the lower 32-bits of Z are checked, it should be less than 60.

```
Z & 0x00000000ffffffff < 60
```

However, when I add the second equation as a constraint, z3 gives me an error.

Here's my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from z3 import *
import sys

s = Solver()
result = int(sys.argv[1], 16)

x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')

s.add(x + y == result)
s.add(x > 0, y > 0)
s.add((x * y) & 0x00000000ffffffff < 60)

while s.check() == sat:
    print s.model()
    s.add(Or(x != s.model()[x], y != s.model()[y]))
```

**Updated:**

Here is the code based on the recommended solution:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from z3 import *
import sys

s = Solver()
x = BitVec('x', 32)
y = BitVec('y', 32)

result = BitVecVal(int(sys.argv[1], 16), 32)

s.add(x + y == result)
s.add(x > 0, y > 0)
s.add(x * y < 10)

print s.check()
print s.model()
```

The binary is 64-bit.

However, the multiplication operation is performed using 32-bit integers as shown below:

```
mov     edx, [rbp+var_14]
mov     eax, [rbp+var_10]
imul    eax, edx
```

So if eax = 0x425a95e5 and edx = 0x7e92fbd8

Then after multiplication using imul instruction, eax will store: 0x00000038.

Both, the Carry Flag and Overflow Flag bits in the EFLAGS register will be set after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you have declared `x` and `y` to be arbitrarily wide integers, as opposed to bit-vectors of a fixed length. Simply change your declarations to match what the underlying bit-size should be. Assuming you want your arithmetic to be done in 32 bits, you'd say:

```py
x = BitVec('x', 32)
y = BitVec('y', 32)
```

instead. You should also declare `result` similarly:

```py
result = BitVecVal(int(sys.argv[1], 16), 32)
```

Once you make these changes, your program should work just fine.

Note that in this case masking with `0x00000000ffffffff` isn't really necessary; since the numbers are already 32-bits wide. You only need to keep it if your `x` and `y` are larger; say 64 bits.

With the above changes, I get the following output when I run your program and call it with `0xC0ED91BD`:

```
[y = 2123561944, x = 1113232869]
[y = 1440310864, x = 1796483949]
[y = 1171875408, x = 2064919405]
... many other lines ..
```

This might look confusing, as the numbers seem to be larger than what you think they should be. But remember that arithmetic over bitvectors is done modulo `2^n` where `n` is the bit-size, so the results are actually correct:

```
>>> 2123561944 + 1113232869 % 2**32 == 0xC0ED91BD
True
>>> 2123561944 * 1113232869 % 2**32 < 60
True
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks. I checked it further and above method is also giving me incorrect solutions. For example, If the desired result is: 0xc23fe810, then I get the solutions as: [y = 2013265920, x = 1245702160]. If you multiply these numbers, you will get: 2507929705198387200 which in hexadecimal is: 22CDF4C780000000. The lower 32-bits are: 0x80000000. In the program, I included the condition, x * y < 3. If I do modulo 2**32 for the above numbers, I get 2147483648.

Comment: 2147483648 happens to be 2^31. So, I think, that condition evaluates to true in z3 because of the overflow. In my case, the multiplication is done by the 64-bit program in x86-64 assembly using imul eax, edx. The output is in eax register. CF and OF flags are set accordingly. I need to make sure that eax is < 0x10.

Comment: Another example of an incorrect result reported by this method: result = 0x3045bd37, solution = [y = 479336633, x = 330540158], [330540158 * 479336633 % 2**32 = 2887364366L]. Could you please check it? Thanks.

Comment: If the underlying algorithm works on 64-bits, then you should declare variables as such. That is, use `x = BitVec('x', 64)` etc.

Comment: The operations are performed using 32-bit registers only. Both the inputs as well as the outputs are 32-bit registers. I have updated the question with the assembly language code as well. When two 32-bit numbers are multiplied in x86 using imul instruction, even if the result is greater than 32-bit, only the 32-bit part of the result is retained. That's why I was performing the bit mask with 0x00000000ffffffff

Comment: I have updated the description in the question. Binary is using the imul instruction for multiplication which is defined here: https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_138.html

Comment: Is it possible to make the multiplication operation in z3 behave according to IMUL ASM instruction? In Z3, if the result of multiplication is > 2147483648, it will show incorrect result. For example: target = 0x3045bd37, solution = [y = 479336633, x = 330540158], [330540158 * 479336633 % 2**32 = 2887364366L], Even though 2887364366 > 10, Z3 still shows that as a possible solution.

Comment: stack-overflow is best suited for single-question/answers. This sort of continued discussion in comments leads to confusion. if your original question is answered, you should accept that as an answer and open up another question. See the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually your code was not exactly answering the question and that is why I asked a follow up question. I can mark it as answered. I also found the answer to the question. The issue was due to signed comparison. We need to use the ULE operator (Unsigned Less than or Equal to) instead of "<" (which performs a signed comparison). When I used ULE, it resolved the issue.